# Use of uninitialized value in substitution (s///) warning in Perl

Tags: perl

I get the warning for the following perl code:

```
my $current_email = '';

$current_email = 'saashtechs@gmail.com';

my $to_email =~ s/^To:(.*)/To: $current_email/m;
```

Warning is `Use of uninitialized value in substitution (s///)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of uninitialized value in substitution (s///) error in PERL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918053/use-of-uninitialized-value-in-substitution-s-error-in-perl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the binding operator `=~`, for search and replace, the value that is searched is the left hand side of the operator.

In your case, this is `$to_email`.

However, in your code, this variable is uninitialized when you use the binding operator, meaning that it has no initial value.

Thus, the error.

References:

- [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut): Regular Expressions tutorial
- [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Binding-Operators): Perl Operators (Binding Operator)